# Powershell Get-Content, want only the first occurrence

Tags: powershell

i'm doing a series of splits to examine each line of a file, and output a formatted version of each line.

Example of input:

```
02/17-07:54:32.290169  [**] [1:1:0] other [**] [Priority: 0] {TCP} 100.100.100.212:6667 -> 192.168.5.81:2848
02/17-07:54:32.335595  [**] [1:1:0] other [**] [Priority: 0] {TCP} 100.100.100.212:6667 -> 192.168.5.81:2848
02/17-07:54:32.335628  [**] [1:1:0] other [**] [Priority: 0] {TCP} 192.168.5.81:2848 -> 100.100.100.212:6667
06/14-06:33:47.258621  [**] [1:1:0] other [**] [Priority: 0] {TCP} 192.168.4.85:4662 -> 69.192.30.179:80
06/14-06:33:47.258621  [**] [1:1:0] other [**] [Priority: 0] {TCP} 192.168.4.85:4662 -> 69.192.30.179:80
06/14-06:33:47.258621  [**] [1:1:0] other [**] [Priority: 0] {TCP} 192.168.4.85:4662 -> 69.192.30.179:80
```

When there are strings with the same connection ID (258621, in this case), I need just the first occurrence.

This gets me the connection ID, but i'm not sure how to disregard any lines that may follow with the same connection ID.

```
Get-Content $logFile -ReadCount 1 | % {

$_.Split()[0].Split(".")[1]

} | Out-File "C:\Log\logout.txt"
```

Output, I only want the first occurrence of 258621:

```
290169
335595
335628
258621
258621
258621
```

The trickier part is that I also need to reformat each line (assuming it isn't a duplicate connection ID) using something like this (ultimately, I don't want the connection ID in the output):

```
'|' + (($_.Split()[9, 11, 4] -replace ':', '|') -join '|') + '|'
```

Desired output:

```
|100.100.100.212|6667|192.168.5.81|2848|other|
|100.100.100.212|6667|192.168.5.81|2848|other|
|192.168.5.81|2848|100.100.100.212|6667|other|
|192.168.4.85|4662|69.192.30.179|80|other|
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `IF` statement in your `ForEach-Object` loop to make sure you have not dealt with this connection ID before.

As it is assigned to a variable `$thisID`, it is not passed to `Out-File` (same for `$connectionIDs`)

```
Get-Content $logFile -ReadCount 1 | % {

    $thisID = $_.Split()[0].Split(".")[1]

    if($thisID -notin $connectionIDs){
        '|' + (($_.Split()[9, 11, 4] -replace ':', '|') -join '|') + '|' 
        [array]$connectionIDs += $thisID
    }
} | Out-File "C:\Log\logout.txt"
```

Output matches what's in your question.

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you!

Comment: gms0ulman, do you know how to further filter out any row where [9] OR [11] do not start with "192.168" ?  I've been playing with .StartsWith but haven't had any success yet.

Comment: @yodish You can add additional criteria to the `IF` statement. This doesn't have to be regex - e.g. `-and $line -notlike <>`. Recommend reading up on `-like/-notlike` and giving it a go.